# Google Maps JS API Suggestion AutocompletionService does not returns the same address all the time

Tags: google-maps-api-3

The Google Maps API Suggestion does not return the same address all the time. We have a probe that runs every 10 minutes, and about 8 times per days the PlaceService.GetPlaceDetails does not return the same address.

Here are the HTTP calls :

Most of the time :

```
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/AutocompletionService.GetPredictions?1s169%20Avenue%20Boll%C3%A9e%2C%20Le%20Mans%2C%20France&4sfr-FR&7scountry%3Afr&15e3&client=*******&callback=_xdc_._ca6qq&token=18520 HTTP/1.1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK ../.. ["169 Avenue Bollée, Le Mans, France", ../..
```

then the Google JS API calls:

```
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/PlaceService.GetPlaceDetails
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
../..
     {
        "long_name" : "169",
        "short_name" : "169",
        "types" : [ "street_number" ]
     },
```

And about 8 times per day :

the same request

```
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/AutocompletionService.GetPredictions?1s169%20Avenue%20Boll%C3%A9e%2C%20Le%20Mans%2C%20France&4sfr-FR&7scountry%3Afr&15e3&client=******&callback=_xdc_._ca6qq&token=123244 HTTP/1.1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK ../.. ["169 Avenue Bollée, Le Mans, France", ../..
```

but the GetPlaceDetails returns another street number (notice the "181-167" instead of "169")

```
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/PlaceService.GetPlaceDetails?2sfr-FR&8sEiMxNjkgQXZlbnVlIEJvbGzDqWUsIExlIE1hbnMsIEZyYW5jZQ&10e3&client=gme-giecovea1&callback=_xdc_._8rimfj&token=108576 HTTP/1.1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
../..
         {
            "long_name" : "181-167",
            "short_name" : "181-167",
            "types" : [ "street_number" ]
         },
```

Does anyone know how it can be possible ? I don't see any other HTTP call between these one. It causes me error in the probe process because it cannot find the corresponding client of the address in 181-167.

Comment: Probably you are hitting different data centers at Google which are not synchronized quite well.

Comment: Thus, either Google can synchronize better the clusters or I make a more robust probe (but more complex) or I mock Google call (but my probe becomes specific and less realistic) or I accept that the probe fails "sometimes" :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Google Map Premium (translated from French) :

> The Places database changes all the time due to the interactions with the Google Services, in order to improve continiously the results. In your case the location is the same (same coords) but the address binded to this location slighty differs. Google results won't be changed. You should either:
>
> - change your code to accept street number range
> - or use the adresse selected by the user

Actually, as the result switches from a accurate adress to a street numbers range, I think it is due to a bad cluster sync as @xomena stated it.

Secondly, we noticed that this "random" address was a building address and in a way Google is right to said that this address cannot be always accurate : [as you can see on Street View](https://www.google.fr/maps/@47.9982733,0.2135826,3a,75y,43.06h,100.53t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1srWQqErwIUEHcZ8F8-7BUpQ!2e0!3e11!7i13312!8i6656!6m1!1e1)

We decided to choose another test address with less risk of low accurate suggestion.